# Change Joomla 1.5 ACL

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I need to allow managers to add users from Joomla 1.5, but can't find the correct MYSQL table to change the permissions.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is a Joomla SE site over at area51.

Comment: @markus There wasnt at this time :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it possible with the standard Joomla! 1.5 setup.

Joomla 1.5's ACL is only partially implemented - it was originally going to be [derived from `phpgacl` but it was never fully implemented](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/Jb-ufv2hzyE/B2_cljAwxcUJ). With the Joomla! 1.6/7/2.5 line it was thrown out completely.

Having, said that to compensate for the limitations of the ACL lots of good extensions where created to address the sort of issue you're looking - you can find these on the [Joomla! Extension Directory Site Access](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access) section.